# Стилизация google maps

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Как сделать переключения типов, что бы были кнопки с изображением карты и спутника:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Искал в документации, нашел параметр mapTypeControlOptions, но там нет такого типа стилей как нужно, однако раньше было именно такое переключение (по дефолту), а потом я поменял что-то (не помню уже что), и такое переключение исчезло.
Как восстановить?